# Can delete file with Windows GUI but not with powershell, both using administrator right

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete a machinekey in the folder "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys" via powershell, but get met with the error "You do not have permmision to delete this file.

If I try to delete the same file via Windows gui I'm allowed to do it.
It's the same Admin account I'm using.

This is the code I'm using.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\19c5cf9c*" | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Could be UAC issue. If you run Powershell as administrator, does the delete succeed?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no. I'm running powershell elevated.